# How to fix errors encountered while processing?

Tags: apt

It all started when I installed an Arc theme for VLC. Afterwards VLC got kind of screwed up so I uninstalled it and tried to install it again. However I've been getting problems using `sudo apt-get [anything]`. The Terminal keeps telling me to use `sudo apt-get install -f` but all I get is an error.

[image: Here's a picture of the Terminal itself]

Answer (score 0):

First, you could/should have copied the text, pasted it into your question, and Formatted with the `{}` button just left of the `image` button.

Second, it looks like it's complaining about `/etc/python2.7/sitecuston.py`. You should move this file to some other directory, do the `sudo apt-get install -f`, then compare and merge the saved copy with the installed copy.

Read the error messages slowly and carefully - programmers try very hard to make them helpful.

Comment: Thanks for the help. Spent a couple of minutes looking out on how to do it (newbie here) and managed to do it without a problem